# expose 32/64bit DLL APIs for 64bit device driver?

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit, driver

I am going to make a device driver for 64 bit platform (i.e. Win7) and I would also like to expose device APIs in DLLs which could be distributed to users writing their applications.

The question is, how could I build such DLLs both for 32bit and 64bit applications?
The problem here is actually only about 32 bit one.

could I just write DLL and compile it in 32 as well as 64bit?
Or do I really need some IPC to wrap 64bit dll so that 32bit application can indirectly invoke device driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation between 32 and 64 bits should take place at the existing user-kernel layer.  Your DLLs will use IOCTL commands to communicate with the driver, and the 32-bit DLL will have to use 64-bit IOCTL structures when the driver is 64-bit.

There's no need to add a second IPC layer.

Comment: also find this on msdn 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563897(v=vs.85).aspx